# Submit button question

Tags: html

Can I turn a link for example `<a href="#">submit</a>` into a submit button for a form? If so how? I'm using PHP, MySQL, XHTML and CSS.

Comment: <a href="javascript:document.forms["myform"].submit();">

Answer (score 4):

You can call submit() on your form. Like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">e</a>
```

Which is something I really would not recommend, but its the answer to your question.

Comment: @Francisco Soto: Yes, that should work, but note that it is against the practices of obtrusive javascript :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I said I would not recommend it :), just answered his question.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real one.

You can fake it with JavaScript, but this violates [Rule 2](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build).

You can use CSS to make a submit button look like a link, but this isn't generally a good idea (although still a better one than using JS). Users expect buttons to submit forms, and for links to just go somewhere. Violating expectations is poor usability.

Answer (score 1):

With javascript you can do a onclick

In jquery:

```
$('theElement').click(function(){ 
// submit the form...
});
```

Edited: (I wrote onclick!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[jQuery](http://jquery.org)** for unobtrusive javascript practices and submit the form:

```
<form id="form_id">
 ...........
</form>

<a href="#" id="submit_link">submit</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  $('#submit_link').click(function(){
    $('#form_id').submit();    
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script language="javascript">
  function submitform()
  {
    document.form1.submit();
  }
</script>

<form name="form1"></form>

<a href="javascript:submitform()">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

*(TESTED ON SAFARI and FF / OSX)* I do not have DOS machine at home.

The answer to the question is Yes.

This is how you would code it in plain Javascript:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <title>Form Submit</title>
      <script>
        window.onload = function(){
          document.getElementById("linksubmit").onclick = function(){
            if(document.getElementById("foo").value != ''){
              document.forms[0].submit();
                  return false;
            }else{
              alert('Please fill in Foo');
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="theform" action="index.html" method="post">
      <label for="foo">Foo</label>
      <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" />
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="linksubmit">Submit</a>
    </form> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

And this how you would code it with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#linksubmit").click(function(){
    if($("#foo").val()!=''){
  $("#theform").submit();
      return false;
    }else{
      alert('Please fill in Foo');
    }
  });
});
```

Just use this piece between the script tags instead of the first example. Also remember to add the jQuery source code. Google has a hosted version that is good to use: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jquery